# Get and set cell value and Id for ClosedXML.Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, closedxml

I am creating a excel file by closedxml. I am able to set its cell value as shown below.

```
worksheet.Cell(rowPosition, cellPosition).Value="abc";
```

What I need is to set an Id of that cell which relates to its value and which is not visible to user. So when I again read this excel file programatically I can use this Id filed as Id is unique for me but not text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As for an Unique thing or Id, you may use your Cell number Ex: A1 as replacement of Id but actually not, it's visible but work as compare to ID as property ID is not available for ClosedXML properties.

Comment: This looks like a promising answer, but I can't quite understand it.  Can you clarify how it solves the problem in the question?

Answer (score 1):

ClosedXml does not expose any invisible properties of the cells.

You could use [Named Ranges](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Defining-Ranges) or [Comments](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Comments-Visibility) to mark the cells, but both are visible to the user in Excel.